# How to get Index Image in ng-bootstrap Carousel

Tags: angular

I have used ng-bootstrap https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples#navigation for showing carousel in angular version 7. And I want to get the current index of the image. I need that for showing background color corresponding with the image. 
Then I see an event (slide) it show me some meta info that I can use to determine the index of the image. (I have 3 images in total)

```
{"prev":"ngb-slide-1","current":"ngb-slide-2","direction":"left"}
```

One problem that when i navigate to other page and go back. 
The meta info starts from ngb-slide-4 instead of ngb-slide-0.

See my link demo here https://angular-ndxybr.stackblitz.io/

Back to my question How I can get the index of the image when it slides?
Thank you very much.

I can work around by extract number from ngb-slide-2 or ngb-slide-5(next time). 
index = number % 3, but it's not correct in case the number of image change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [NgbSlide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api#NgbSlide) directive has an `id` input property that is auto-generated if you don't set it. However, you can set it to make sure that it always gives you the image index:

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" (slide)="onSlide($event)">
  <ng-template *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index" ngbSlide [id]="'slideId_' + i">
    <img [src]="image" alt="Random slide">
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

The index can then be extracted from the `id`:

```
onSlide(event) {
  const imageIndex = parseInt(event.current.replace("slideId_", ""), 10);
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-as4xyq?file=src%2Fapp%2FHomePageComponent%2Fhome-page.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks for this. Works fine.  Feels like a bit of a workaround though.  Shame index isn't tracked formally in the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `(slid)` callback of `ngbSlide` like this:

In your `component.html`:

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template (slid)="activeIndex = i" *ngFor="let slide of slides; index as i" ngbSlide>
    <div>
      <!-- Slide content -->
      activeIndex: {{activeIndex}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

In your `component.ts`:

```
activeIndex: number = 0;
slides: any[] = []; // e.g. img urls
```

#### Example: Lazy loading images

An application of this could be lazy loading images in a carousel:

In your `component.html`:

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="imgUrls.length>0">
  <ng-template (slid)="activeImageIndex = i" *ngFor="let imageUrl of imgUrls; index as i" ngbSlide>
    <img *ngIf="i === activeImageIndex || i === activeImageIndex+1 || i === activeImageIndex-1 || (activeImageIndex === 0 && i === imgUrls.length-1) || (activeImageIndex === imgUrls.length-1 && i===0)" [src]="imageUrl">
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Note: The `*ngIf` in the `<img>` tag will make sure, that the following images will be loaded:

- the previous one (or the last one, if the current one is the first)
- the current one
- the next one (or the first one, if the current one is the last)

If you're using animations, this will make smooth transitions.

In your `component.ts`:

```
activeImageIndex : number = 0;
imgUrls = ['https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200', 'https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/200', 'https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/200']; // e.g. img urls
```

This way, only the current and the next image will be downloaded reducing traffic.